# R, max value for factor

Tags: r, max

hi if this question has been asked, please redirect - I cannot see it directly.

I want to use R, and have a simple dataframe: 
the first column is an ID, the second is a score.
Each ID has 36 rows and a corresponding score.
There are several thousand IDs.

I would like to generate a summary containing:
1 entry for each unique ID with their maximum score over their 36 rows.

I am also new to R, but know the following:

apply(dataframe, 2, max) would give the maximum, but not broken down by ID.

I know that there are a series of "apply" functions that can be to apply a function over a table, but I don't know how to combine to get what I want.

If it was in Excel it would be the equivalent of a simple Pivot table - but I want to learn how to do it efficiently in R.

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use one of the aggregating functions.   In `base R`. we can use `aggregate` with the formula method.  The `.` on the LHS of `~` specifies all the other variables except the grouping variable 'ID' which is on the RHS of `~`.  We specify the `max` as the `FUN` and it will give a summary dataset of `max` value of each column grouped by 'ID'.

```
aggregate(.~ID, df, FUN=max)
```

Or another option is `dplyr`.  We group by 'ID' and use `summarise_each` with `max` inside the `funs` to get the `max` value of each column.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(max))
```

Or we can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Grouped by the 'ID' column, we get the `max` of each column by looping the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) with `lapply`.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, max) , by = ID]
```

If there is only single column other than the "ID", we can use `summarise` instead of `summarise_each` i.e.

```
   df %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      summarise(score=max(score))
```

Similar code for `data.table` in case of a single column is

```
  setDT(df)[, list(score=max(score)), by = ID]
```

Comment: Outstanding. My first post and a great answer to help me solve the problem - many thanks.